# Proof the converse of theorem is false

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Q: If limit of $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $c$, is $L$
Then limit of absolute value $f(x)$, as $x$ approaches $c$, is absolute value $L$
How do I prove the converse is false with precise definition of limit

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Think of a function which very rapidly changes sign in such a manner that the limit doesn't even exist. (eg a function which is $1$ sometimes and $-1$ other times) You should think about when exactly "sometimes" is

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 & x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-1 & x\in\mathbb{R\setminus\mathbb{Q}}
\end{cases}$$

$\lim_{x\to0}|f(x)|=1$, obviously.  Now show that, for any value of $a$ and any neighborhood $(-\delta,\delta)$ of $0$, there is an $x$ in that neighborhood such that $|f(x)-a|>0.5$.